# Android Appcompat v21 - use old spinner style

Tags: android, android-widget, android-spinner, android-appcompat

I am using appcompat v21 in a project, but I do not like the new spinner it comes with by default. This new spinner comes only with a small downward-facing arrow that indicates it presence. I would prefer the old spinner used in 4.x versions of android which come with an EditText-like feature underlining the widget's content and an arrow in the bottom right corner.

How can I achieve this spinner style while still using appcompat v21?

The udesired spinner style:

**photo of undesired spinner:**

[image: photo of undesired spinner]

**photo of desired spinner:**

[image: photo of desired spinner]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can simply set the Style of the Spinner to `Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner`

#### Example

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner" />
```

This will give you the old Spinner-Style back though there are two drawbacks:

1. This solution only works with API-Level 14 and up (no that big of a deal)
2. The appearance of the DropDown Popup-Window is managed by the "framework" - this means on pre Lollipop devices the Popup-Window will appear below the `Spinner`. Starting with Lollipop it'll be above the Spinner (afaik there's no way to change this). With regard to this see the following comparison (on the left pre Lollipop)

[image: spinner comparison]

If you wish to customize the rows of the DropDown you can do so by calling [setDropDownViewResource(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#setDropDownViewResource%28int%29) on the adapter of the Spinner with the reference to your own layout.

Comment: @reVerse : But when I use "/Widget.Material.Light.Spinner", it still shows dark theme for lollipop and above.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_nav"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:overlapAnchor="false"
    style="@style/Platform.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"/>
```